# Mongoose - Custom sorting by a string field in specific order

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have a model with some `type` field:

```
const petOptions = Object.freeze({
  Dog: "Dog",
  Cat: "Cat",
  Parrot: "Parrot",
  Other: "Other",
});

const petSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
   {
      ...,
      type: {type: String, enum: petOptions, required: true},
   }
)

const Pet = mongoose.model("Pet", petSchema)
```

when I'm running `find` on that model, I need to be able to sort by specific order, meaning:

- first all documents with `type = "Parrot"`
- then all documents with `type = "Cat"`
- then all documents with `type = "Dog"`
- then all others (all documents with `type = "Other"`)

I can do that on the JS code itself but wonder if this is something that is possible to do using the mongoose `find().sort()`

```
Pet.find({}).sort(?)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) to prepare a field you can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by in the next aggregation stage:

```
await Pet.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            sortField: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$type", "Parrot" ] }, then: 0 },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$type", "Cat" ] }, then: 1 },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$type", "Dog" ] }, then: 2 },
                    ],
                    default: 3
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { sortField: 1 }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HH2A4AnT9NB)